# How to read WebAssembly file it JavaScript from the local file system with native tools

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I am looking for a way to structure my JavaScript test and read a simple binary WebAssembly file i.e. wasm from the local file system i.e. not in the  browser application without using third party tools like node. So far i have found that this can be done with node fs object.  but I do not want to load such a huge tool only to read one file. 
i.e.

I am looking of the way to replace a node call like this

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('myTestFile.wasm');
var buffer = new Uint8Array(file).buffer;
```

how will that look like in a JavaScript without node and without browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JavaScript engines have a non-browser build of their source code which runs on the command line. JSC has `jsc`, V8 has `d8`, SpiderMonkey `js`, and ChakraCore `ch`.

Those are used by each browser vendor for testing, and inevitably we sometimes need to read ASCII or binary files. There's unfortunately not really a standard for such functionality, but I've found that this works for my purpose:

```
const readAsBinary = filename => {
if (typeof process === 'object' && typeof require === 'function') {
    const binary = require('fs').readFileSync(file);
    return !binary.buffer ? new Uint8Array(binary) : binary;
} else
    return typeof readbuffer === 'function'
        ? new Uint8Array(readbuffer(file))
        : read(file, 'binary');
};

const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(new WebAssembly.Module(readAsBinary(filename)), {});
```

This will *only* work in node.js or an engine's shell, and *not* in a browser.

Comment: Hello JS, but this requires node if I am reading this correctly and i do not want to use node i..e i want plain simple java script

Comment: @Tito no, it detects node.js and uses it if available only. Otherwise it detect shells that expose `readbuffer`, and if that's not the case it uses `read`.

Comment: @JFBastien isn't the last resort (if node.js and `readerbuffer()` are not detected) just a infinitely recursive call? That seems like a bug.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts right you are! Fixed. I changed existing code, and renamed the case I wasn't hitting :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you base64-encode the .wasm file then you can include it directly in the JavaScript like this:

```
Module.wasmBinaryFile = "data:application/wasm;base64,AGFzbQEAAAAByQ/AAWACf38Bf2A...";
```

Comment: This will also work in a browser, unlike the other answer!